# Using Puppet to manage shell commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet, deployment, vagrant

For example lets attempt to let Puppet [install the opengeo-suite](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/ubuntu/suite.html).

To do something like

```
wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

we can use

```
exec {'getKey':
    command => "wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -",
}

exec {'addRepo':
    command => "echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list",
}
```

**Question #1:** If we run the puppet script again, won't the wget and echo be run twice? We will end up with  duplicate repo in `/etc/apt/sources.d`. Running `package { "opengeo-suite": }` twice doesn't attempt to install the package twice, it simply ensures that its installed.

**Question #2:** Doing `apt-get install opengeo-suite` there are several promopts for user input. Will Puppet somehow know the default input to use, or will it crash?

Comment: Not to contradict any existing answers, but to add: `apt` also uses the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for repositories. Each file can contain one or more entries, and you can manage each file via Puppet `file` resources. *Much* easier than trying to work up idempotency via `grep` or other tools.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you don't prevent it, the commands will be run at every puppet run, including multiple entries in the `sources.list`. This should not happen, as Puppet expects that `exec` calls are idempotent. One way around this is to to create "check" files and run the `exec` only if the check file is not present. See [the doc](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#exec) to learn how to do this. Also note that there exist [user-contributed modules](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt) to maintain apt repos with Puppet.
2. I haven't used Puppet on an apt-based system (yet), but I guess that Puppet or the apt module I linked above is clever enough to handle this. If not, [see this](http://snowulf.com/2008/12/04/truly-non-interactive-unattended-apt-get-install/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use onlyif into exec.
The test has to return true in order to execute the command, in your case see bellow (the PUBLIC_KEY_ID it is the key id of the apt provider)

```
exec {'getKey':
  command => "wget -qO- http://apt.opengeo.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -",
  onlyif  => "test `apt-key list |grep PUBLIC_KEY_ID | wc -l ` -eq 0"
}

exec {'addRepo':
  command => "echo "deb http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu lucid main" /etc/apt/sources.list",
  onlyif  => "test `grep http://apt.opengeo.org/suite/v3/ubuntu /etc/apt/sources.list | wc -l ` -eq 0"
}
```